# Unable to find the element in selenium which is having on-click attribute

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, xpath-2.0

I am trying to find an element using Selenium. I tried both using `x-path` 
 and `class name`, but both ways failed to click on the element.

Specifically, I am trying to find the new account link element, which is basically an `onclick` attribute.

```
<a onclick="getDashboard().newAccount(event)" href="#" class="dashboard_menu_div_main">
```

Below the full code.

```
<div class="dashboard" style="">
    <div class="dashboard_context">
        <div class="dashboard_context_title">Welcome Muamalaty Portal</div>In relation to the provision of Services and supply of Products by Etisalat Website Customer of Etisalat Website shall observe and be bound by Etisalat Conditions applicable to each.
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard_Body dashboard-content">
            <div class="dashboard_menu_div dashboard-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="getDashboard().newAccount(event)" href="#" class="dashboard_menu_div_main">
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_number">01</div>
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_img">
                                <img src="/cim/resources/images/produts/dashboard/new-account.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_menu_fonts">New Account</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="getDashboard().standAlone(event,'714857547');" href="#" class="dashboard_menu_div_main">
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_number">05</div>
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_img">
                                <img src="/cim/resources/images/produts/dashboard/standalone.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_menu_fonts">Standalone Devices</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="new PendingOrders().init({evt:event});" href="#" class="dashboard_menu_div_main">
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_number">08</div>
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_img">
                                <img src="/cim/resources/images/produts/dashboard/pending-orders.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_menu_fonts">Pending Orders</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="getDashboard().newPreOrder(event)" href="#" class="dashboard_menu_div_main">
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_number">16</div>
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_img">
                                <img src="/cim/resources/images/produts/dashboard/new-preorder.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_menu_fonts">New PreOrder</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="new Miscellaneous().init({evt:event});" href="#" class="dashboard_menu_div_main">
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_number">22</div>
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_img">
                                <img src="/cim/resources/images/produts/dashboard/miscellaneous.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="dashboard_menu_menu_fonts">Miscellaneous services</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i tried below code since there is 7 iframe i tried to click on the location in all the frame and every time it  is getting failed in all the frames.

```
for(int i=0;i<=s1;i++) {
    try {
        driver.switchTo().frame(i);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("./div[@class=\"dashboard\"]/div[2]/div[@class=\"dashboard_menu_div dashboard-menu\"]/ul/li/a[@onclick=\"getDashboard().newAccount(event)\"]@onclick")).click();

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("failed "+i+" time");
    }
}
```

Another paths I've tried are:

```
//driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[contains(@onclick,'getDashboard().newAccount(event)')]")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//dashboard_menu_div > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)")).click();
```

Comment: There is an HTML form tag inside the frame which consist an attribute like Type=hidden,May be for this reason we are unable to find the element

Answer (score 0):

1. for below `xpath` you tried,  it should `//a` not `.//input`

   ```
   //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[contains(@onclick,'getDashboard().newAccount(event)')]")).click();
   ```
2. If above `xpath`, after changed still does not work, please add some debug code to make sure you switch into the correct `iframe`. After that you can remove the debug code. For debug code you can find the element which easy to be located in the same `iframe`, like the title: "Welcome Muamalaty Portal"

   ```
   try {
       driver.switchTo().frame(i);

       //debug code begin
       String title = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.dashboard_context_title"))
                       .getText();
       System.out.println("Title: " + title);
       //debug code end

       // click New Accont Link
       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[onclick*='newAccount']")).click();

   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println("failed "+i+" time");
   }
   ```

Comment: its not working still am getting the same exception.

Comment: its not working as still am getting the same exception. even for debugging code we are getting the exception .Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.dashboard_context_title"}

Comment: You use a for loop and click the New Account link in each loop, I doubt not every iframe has New Account link. You should switch to the correct iframe directly, rather than using for loop.

Comment: thanks Yong after switching to the correct frame its working now.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you provided, we need to construct an unique `cssSelector` or a `xpath` to identify and click on the `WebElement` as follows:

- **`xpath`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dashboard_menu_div dashboard-menu']//following::a[1]")).click();
  ```
- **`cssSelector`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.dashboard_menu_div.dashboard-menu > a:nth-child(1)")).click();
  ```

Comment: Still am getting same exception for both the selector ,like Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.dashboard_menu_div.dashboard-menu > a:nth-child(1)"}

Answer (score 0):

After Switching to the correct iframe its working fine.
Thanks for the support guys.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(6);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mainForm:productsList']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().frame(6); driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".dashboard_menu_div_main")).click();
```